# Kendo Grid Columns Display ActionLink

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid with multiple columns, but I want to display the Name of the Doc and when I click it to get the path of that Doc.

View

```
 columns.Bound(od => od.DocumentListName).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#=generateTemplate(DocumentListName)#");
```

JavaScript function that displays the list of Docs

```
 function generateTemplate(DocumentList) {

        var template = "<ul>"
        if (DocumentList == null || DocumentList == undefined) {

            template = template + "<li>N/A</li>";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < DocumentList.length; i++) {
                template = template + "<li>" + DocumentList[i] + "</li>";
            }
        }
        return template + "</ul>";
    }
```

And my ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult GetDocuments(ViewModel VM)
        {
            using (var db = new DB())
            {
               var docName = db.Documents.Include("Doc").Where(x => x.Id == VM.Id).Select(z => z.Name).ToList();
                if (docName.Count() != 0) {

                }
                Vm.DocumentListName = docName;
                var docPath = db.Documents.Include("Doc").Where(x => x.Id == Vm.Id).Select(z => z.Path).ToList();
                VM.DocumentPathList = docPath;
                return Json(VM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
```

I know I can display the Path as ActionLink this way

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(@item.DocumentPathList.ToString(), "GetDocuments", "Controller") </text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='#=DocumentPathList#</a>").Title("Docs");
```

But how can I combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function generateTemplate(DocumentList) {

        var template = "<ul>";
        if (DocumentList == null || DocumentList == undefined) {

            template = template + "<li> </li>";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < DocumentList.length; i++) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "Controller")?filename=' + DocumentListName[i];
                template = template + "<a href='" + url + "'>" + DocumentList[i] + "</a> ";
            }
        }
        return template + "</ul>";
    }
```